# How to display Model attribute as a fixed display string in Django InlineFormSet?

Tags: django, formset

**Edit: Part of my question has been answered so here is the remaining part**

I have a Django InlineFormSet that allows users to edit multiple Score objects corresponding to a Report. Each Score is tied to an Indicator (indicates what area of performance is being scored).

[This is what the form looks like right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYXMZ.png)

How can I extract the text of the initial Indicator choice in the Indicator dropdown choicefields and display them instead as fixed, un-editable text labels for the Score choicefields?

My models and views are below.

**models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# Indicators
class Indicator(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    # Order is an integer indicating how the areas should be sequentially ordered
    # The smallest integer should be listed first
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        return self.value

# Reports
class Report(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

# Possible numeric score choice and associated display color
class ScoreChoice(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        return str(self.value)

# Actual scores, with the value as one of the score choices
# and belonging to a report and indicator
class Score(models.Model):
    value = models.ForeignKey(ScoreChoice, null=True)
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator, null=True)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def report_create(request, pk):
    indicators = Indicator.objects.order_by('order')

    # Create a new report for the country and associated report form
    report = Report(country=Country.objects.get(pk=pk), author=request.user)
    report_form = ReportForm(instance=report)

    ScoreInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Report, Score, fields=('indicator', 'value'), 
    extra=len(indicators), can_delete=False)
    formset = ScoreInlineFormSet(instance=report, initial=[{'indicator': i} for i in indicators])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        report_form = ReportForm(request.POST, instance=report)
        formset = ScoreInlineFormSet(request.POST)

        if report_form.is_valid():
            created_report = report_form.save(commit=False)
            formset = ScoreInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=created_report)

            if formset.is_valid():
                created_report.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect('report_detail', pk=created_report.pk)

    return render(request, 'ghsanavigator/report_create.html',
     {'formset': formset, 'report_form': report_form, 'indicators': indicators, 'country': Country.objects.get(pk=pk).name})
```

### ----------

**The first, and already solved question is summarized below for your reference (answered by vgrubes)**

[Currently, the form looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLkbm.png)

How can I change so that the dropdown fields are populated not by "ScoreChoice Object" but by the actual Score.ScoreChoice.value? Same for the indicator dropdown fields.

I was able to achieve #2 for a simple ModelForm by doing the following, but I have no idea how to do this for an InlineFormSet! And I have no idea on how to do #1.

```
class ScoreChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % (obj.value)

class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    value = ScoreChoiceField(queryset=ScoreChoice.objects.all())
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide only a partial answer to your question. You can specify a **unicode** method in your models that will return a string instead of a model object instance.

```
class Indicator(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.name:
            return self.name
```

This will fix your Indicator Object problem. And in the similar manner you can fix your ScoreChoice Object problem.

Comment: Thanks! This allowed me to display strings in the drop-down menu :) Note that I am using Python 3 so instead of __unicode__ I had to use __str__.